# Why HTML WebSocket access Socket.io web socket server failed?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

As socket.io said, it supports WebSocket, so, I use HTML5 standard web socket api to access socket.io server, but I always get below error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/' failed: Connection
>   closed before receiving a handshake response

Then, I tried to use socket.io client in js to access socket.io server, it works, and by chrome network monitoring, i found it using web socket protocol correctly.

Did anyone ever try W3C Websocket api to access socket.io server and met similar issue? or any ideas or clues for my problem? appreciated!

Test code is here: https://github.com/piginzoo/socketiotest

Comment: Now I use socket.io 0.9 to adapt the [AndroidASync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync) project, it now only support socket.io 0.9.

Comment: Had exact same problem with Chrome and IE-11. The latter gives a more specific error message: "WebSocket Error: Network Error 12152, The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response"
It does look like socket.io is not really compatible with Websocket API as implemented by either Chrome or IE-11

Answer (score 2):

Note: Socket.IO is not a WebSocket implementation. Although Socket.IO indeed uses WebSocket as a transport when possible, it adds some metadata to each packet: the packet type, the namespace and the ack id when a message acknowledgement is needed. That is why a WebSocket client will not be able to successfully connect to a Socket.IO server, and a Socket.IO client will not be able to connect to a WebSocket server (like ws://echo.websocket.org) either.
And I find this in socketio github issues:
**Socket.IO is not a WebSocket server. Please see [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) instead.**
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/3022

Answer (score 1):

The error message you got was because you used the wrong url. The error message "Connection closed before receiving a handshake response" actually told you this (*not receiving a response*)

It should be `'ws://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket'` 
Check here https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#With-custom-path & https://socket.io/docs/internals/ for details

e.g.

```
"EIO=3"               # the current version of the Engine.IO protocol
```

**BUT** as other answer said and actually that was [what socket.io readme said](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io)

> Although Socket.IO indeed uses WebSocket as a transport when possible, it adds some metadata to each packet: the packet type, the namespace and the ack id when a message acknowledgement is needed. That is why a WebSocket client will not be able to successfully connect to a Socket.IO server, and a Socket.IO client will not be able to connect to a WebSocket server.

I have tested that to verify both [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) & browser native Websocket can't not connect to a Socket.IO server. They are both immediately disconnected from Socket.IO server after they connects, with Socket.IO server send out the error message `socket id xxx has disconnected with reason parse error`

The ws author also mentioned here https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/1390

> using plain WebSocket to talk with a Socket.IO server does not work seamlessly.

If you want to use browser native Websocket you can use ws can server.

Answer (score 0):

We had exactly the same problem. Ended up with [ws](https://github.com/einaros/ws) websockets. Not sure may be there is better solution.